# can't find SQL code for XSD schema tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, xsd, strongly-typed-dataset

The following snippet below came from a *.xsd (XML Schema built in Visual Studio) file.  I'm trying to figure out where the SQL code lives for the data that can be retrieved with these Strongly Typed .NET tables.  I looked everywhere, and cannot find it.  Only two of the tables match actual table names in my database.  Are these primary and foreign keys configured in Visual Studio for this XSD or are these keys found in the SQL database?  If I double click the *.xsd, I can see the tables, but I don't know what data is queried from the database unless I use the SQL profiler.  If someone can explain, that would be great.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the SQL generated at runtime by System.Data?

Comment: I don't know.  Is it?  How is the SQL generated if there is no Query dragged into the Designer?  That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this PDF to be the best resource online so far:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/visualstudiohks/chapter/hack49.pdf

Strongly Typed Datasets starts on page 49.  The only problem is that it isn't helping me answer the question I had.  When I drag a table from the Server Explorer to the *.xsd file, a TableAdaptor gets created with a method called Fill,GetData().  When created manually, this doesn't get created.  It also says it automatically updates the web.config file with connection string information.  However, the tables I'm trying to figure out don't have this TableAdaptor.  The keys don't seem to be related to SQL at all.  They are purely based on the Table in the Visual Studio XSD Designer based on columns created there.  I'd still like to know how the data is ultimately mapped to SQL and to what tables.